# Automapper How to change mapping dynamically

Tags: automapper

I'm connecting to some WebService and receiving Dictionary
that contains keys: "firstName", "lastName", "otherfirstName", "otherLastName".

I have object Person

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

Once according to some context I should create my object Person by mapping values from "firstName" and "lastName" and in another case by mapping from "otherfirstName" and "otherlastName"

If I can create only one mapping function how can I map to other person and to change between them dynamically?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Response, Person>()                
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dict["firstName"] : "") ))
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dict["lastName"] : "") ));
```

I saw some use in Profiles, but I'm not sure how to use it in my case.

***Edited***

```
public class FirstMapper : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Person>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dct["firstName"]))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dct["lastName"]));

    }
}


public class SecondMapper : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Person>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dct["otherfirstName"]))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Dct["otherlastName"]));

    }
}


 public class Src
     {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Dct { get; set; }
    }
```

My Test class

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Src src = new Src();
        src.Dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        src.Dct["firstName"] = "La";
        src.Dct["lastName"] = "Nu";
        src.Dct["otherfirstName"] = "Fe";
        src.Dct["otherlastName"] = "oooo";

        Person person = new Person();

        ConfigurationStore store   = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
        store.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        MappingEngine engine = new MappingEngine(store) ;

        //add mappings via Profiles or CreateMap

        store.AddProfile(new FirstMapper());

        person = engine.Map<Person>(src);
```

}

I have exception on the last line: ""Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping......."

Comment: Just choose profile depending on the context.

Comment: @alehro , thanks for response.
I edited the post.
When I add profile dynamically I get exception that mapping doesn't exist.